# Amazon SES Mail System Queue

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

Now we have a Account verification Email System which use AWS SES system for email triggering. now we have a Max Send Rate: 14 emails/second supposed if we have a large amount of user say 3000 registrations at a time.

I have some questions?

1. Is it go by a Queue with FIFO basis?
2. or its will triger a server load?
3. Did i need to develop something for Queue System?

   *Sending Quota: send 50000 emails per 24 hour period
   Quota Used: 0% as of 2017-02-02 14:23 UTC+5:30
   Max Send Rate:  14 emails/second
   Last updated:   2017-02-02 14:23 UTC+5:30*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to develop the queue system on your end. SES does not queue up the emails for you. If you try to send faster than your SES service limit allows you will get errors.

Comment: Obviously Amazon SQS would be the queue system of choice when using AWS. You might also look at the MoonMail project https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail

Comment: Great, Thanks for your Valuable Suggestion Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You would require and API of SES to send email through it via ur web application to you registered users. the number of you emails are not that large so i as per maths it will take 12.5 Mins to send 3000 emails. if you regularly have this huge size of email then i would suggest you to raise a service limit increase for per second mails from 14 to larges as per your need, once you explain the use case of this higher amount of send mail per second they will review and may approve. Make sure u explain your use case properly to avoid chance of negative answer from aws support team.

For api use below click here [LINK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html)

In case you already have web app which just required smtp details and configuration then you can just directly use it by getting form ses sending configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Parth.

we already added API with our website,  //12.5 Mins to send 3000 // so its automatically trigger first come first out, am i right?